Setting up Keycloak using keycloak-js on nextjs app - context values not updating
i'm trying to set up keycloak on my next-js app using keycloak-js, It needs to be setup in a way where it is able to do something like the screenshot attachedkeycloak required structure
So the journey is as follows from the UI:
The user clicks on login, it redirects to keycloak
Upon signing in, fetch the token returned from logging in from the keycloak side
Send this token to our BE for further validations using this token
This is my local code setup for keycloak:

src/utils/keycloak.js:

import Keycloak from "keycloak-js";

const keycloak =
  typeof document !== "undefined"
    ? new Keycloak({
        url: "https://keycloak.****.***.cloud/",
        realm: "*****",
        clientId: "***-*****-app",
      })
    : null;

export default keycloak;


src/context/AuthContext:

"use client";

// contexts/AuthContext.tsx
import React, {
  createContext,
  useContext,
  useEffect,
  useMemo,
  useState,
} from "react";
import keycloak from "@/utils/keycloak";
import { setCookie, getCookie, deleteCookie } from "cookies-next";

interface User {
  sub: string;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  preferred_username: string;
}

interface AuthContextType {
  isAuthenticated: boolean;
  login: () => Promise<void>;
  logout: () => void;
  token: string | null;
  user: User | null;
}

const defaultAuthContext: AuthContextType = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  login: async () => {
    console.warn("login function not initialized");
  },
  logout: () => {
    console.warn("logout function not initialized");
  },
  token: null,
  user: null,
};

const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContextType>(defaultAuthContext);

export const AuthProvider: React.FC<{ children: React.ReactNode }> = ({
  children,
}) => {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
  const [token, setToken] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const [user, setUser] = useState<User | null>(null);

  const login = async () => {
    try {
      const authenticated = await keycloak.init({ onLoad: "login-required" });
      if (authenticated) {
        setIsAuthenticated(true);
        const accessToken = keycloak.token || "";
        setToken(accessToken);
        setCookie("access_token", accessToken, {
          secure: true,
          sameSite: "strict",
        });
        fetchUserInfo(accessToken);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Keycloak initialization failed:", error);
    }
  };

  const logout = () => {
    keycloak.logout();
    deleteCookie("access_token");
    setIsAuthenticated(false);
    setUser(null);
    setToken(null);
  };

  const fetchUserInfo = async (accessToken: string) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_KEYCLOAK_URL}/realms/${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_KEYCLOAK_REALM}/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo`,
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
          },
        }
      );
      if (response.ok) {
        const data: User = await response.json();
        setUser(data);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Failed to fetch user info:", error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // Restore token from cookies on app load
    const storedToken = getCookie("access_token") as string | null;
    if (storedToken) {
      setToken(storedToken);
      setIsAuthenticated(true);
      keycloak.token = storedToken;
      fetchUserInfo(storedToken);
    }
  }, []);

  const authContextValue = useMemo(
    () => ({ isAuthenticated, login, logout, token, user }),
    [isAuthenticated, login, logout, token, user]
  );

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={authContextValue}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);


Auth Provider wrapped around layout in src/app/[locale]/layout.tsx

import ThemeRegistry from "@/components/ThemeRegistry/ThemeRegistry";
import { locales } from "@/config";
import { NotificationsProvider } from "@/context/Notifications";
import ToastProvider from "@/context/ToastProvider";
import { AppRouterCacheProvider } from "@mui/material-nextjs/v14-appRouter";
import GlobalStyles from "@mui/material/GlobalStyles";
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { NextIntlClientProvider, useMessages } from "next-intl";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import { notFound } from "next/navigation";
import { PropsWithChildren } from "react";
import "../global.css";
import { AuthProvider } from "@/context/AuthContext/AuthContext";
import ReactQueryClientProvider from "./components/ReactQueryClientProvider";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Researcher Registry",
  description: "Researcher Registry homepage",
};

type RootLayoutProps = PropsWithChildren<{
  params: { locale: string };
}>;

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
  params: { locale },
}: RootLayoutProps) {
  if (!locales[locale]) notFound();

  const messages = useMessages();

  return (
    
      <html lang={locale}>
        <body className={inter.className}>
        <AuthProvider>
          <NextIntlClientProvider locale={locale} messages={messages}>
            <AppRouterCacheProvider>
              <NotificationsProvider>
                <ReactQueryClientProvider>
                  <ThemeRegistry>
                    <ToastProvider>
                      <GlobalStyles
                        styles={{
                          [".MuiGrid-item .MuiGrid-container"]: {
                            maxWidth: "initial",
                          },
                        }}
                      />
                      {children}
                    </ToastProvider>
                  </ThemeRegistry>
                </ReactQueryClientProvider>
              </NotificationsProvider>
            </AppRouterCacheProvider>
          </NextIntlClientProvider>
          </AuthProvider>
        </body>
      </html>
    
  );
}

The Problem: The issue that I am seeing with this setup is that, once i'm redirected to the keycloak login page and sign in, I am redirected back to the homepage (which is fine) but none of the context values from above are updated, I think it's because the redirect interrupts the flow of the keycloak.init().then(). functionality so that the then is never executed. But i'm unsure if there. is something else that i'm missing here.
Further side question, is there way around a potential situation where i'm able to login via keycloak BUT authentication from my BE fails, so i'm then able to pushback that keycloak sign in and the force the user back out ?
Tried multiple different implementations of the same thing, all expecting that the context values should be updating, but for me they are not. I need 'isAuthenticated' to be updated to true and the token value from the keycloak login response to be assigned to the token context value
